# Copying and pasting columns and rows linearly using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel

since a week I'm infront of the same problem. I basically have to manipulate a bunch of files which are formatted in a way I haven't worked with before.

Here is an example I build myself to illustrate the problem since I can't share the file.

Excerpt from excel:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hello | my | N/A | kyle | whats |
| name | is | N/A | your | name? |

So basically, the data I want to extract is spread around different columns in the same row, but it does belong to different columns if we want to properly read it.
In this case to make the sentence make sense of course this is what we would want:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| hello | my |
| name | is |
| kyle | whats |
| your | name? |

My approach so far was of course to read the excel file, specify the columns we want to read, which are A, B, D, E. After this I tried multiple things, I tried setting up key:value pairs to transfer the pair "kyle" and "whats" to the row under "name" and "is".

However it never worked.

I would do it manually at this point but I need to automate this for 50 something files, so it would still be better to write a script that can do this.

Could I get my problem across?

Comment: `pd.concat([df[["A", "B"], df[["D", "E"]].rename(columns={"D": "A", "E": "B"}])`?

Comment: I tried this (with the indices): new_df = pd.concat([df[["0", "1"]], df[["3", "4"]].rename(columns={"3": "0", "4": "1"})], ignore_index=True)

However it didn't work as its out of bound. This is my code before that line:
import pandas as pd

excel_path = "/Users/Kyle/Desktop/pandas_test.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel(excel_path, header=None)

df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', inplace=True)

df.drop(2, axis=1, inplace=True)
new_df = pd.concat([df[["0", "1"]], df[["3", "4"]].rename(columns={"3": "0", "4": "1"})], ignore_index=True)

print(new_df.heead())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the rows have to be in order?

If not you could just do:

```
dfx = df[['Column A', 'Column B']].copy()
dfx2 = df['Column D', 'Column E']].copy()

dfx2 = dfx2.rename(columns = {'Column D': 'Column A', 'Column E': 'Column B'})

df = pd.concat([dfx, dfx2])
```

If the order does matter then you could do something like:

```
dfx = df[['Column A', 'Column B']].copy()


# times two because resulting df after concat will be twice as long
dfx['row_num'] = list(range(0, (len(dfx) * 2), 2)) #goes 0, 2, 4, 6 etc.

dfx2 = df['Column D', 'Column E']].copy()

dfx2['row_num'] = list(range(1, (len(dfx2) * 2), 2)) #goes 1, 3, 5, 7 etc.
dfx2 = dfx2.rename(columns = {'Column D': 'Column A', 'Column E': 'Column B'})

df = pd.concat([dfx, dfx2])

df = df.sort_values('row_num').reset_index(drop=True).copy()
df = df.drop(['row_num'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, somehow that worked and they were in the same order although I used the first approach!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always want to follow the same pattern to 'decode' the table I'd first breakdown the DataFrame in two,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['hello', 'my', 'N/A', 'kyle', 'whats'], 
                  ['name', 'is', 'N/A', 'your', 'name?']]),
                  columns=['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C', 'Column D', 'Column E'])
            
df1 = df[['Column A', 'Column B']]
df2 = df[['Column D', 'Column E']]
```

Before rejoining the DataFrames I had to change the column name so that it rejoin correctly. Otherwise it would create a 4x4 dataframe.

```
df2=df2.rename(columns={'Column D':'Column A', 'Column E':'Column B'})
final = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

I'm not sure how I'd expand it to a more generic case. If your objective is only to form sentences I could also use `df.to_numpy().flatten()` on the `df1` and `df2` coupled with `' '.join()`. Hope it helped solve your problem.